# Timeout expired timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool

Tags: sql, connection-pooling

Our Server seems to have slowed down when trying to execute an SQL Query. We may have some un-closed connection and the server was overflowed. Can someone please help me on how to find if I have un-closed connections.

I tried sp_who, Activity Monitor and SQL Profiler but couldn't really find anything.

Comment: Add the tag of the DBMS used.